# I still have a lot of space left in my phone memory & storage But on some application its showing error "Your phone memory is Low"

Tags: java, android, memory

[Your phone's memory is low - error message on my android application using camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jlk1.jpg)

"**Your phone's memory is low**" notice appears on my Android application (java), which uses a custom camera, at random.
Is there a way for Android to catch this issue.I  need to handle this without user interaction within my programme.
Any Java method to find this? I experimented with deleting the cache after an action(on destoy,cleared cache). But that doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Maybe the error refers to RAM, not FLASH ROM (storage). This may be caused by too many apps running in parallel, or few apps taking too much memory in total.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri checked that also RAM ia about 2GB available as free.